# FirebaseError: Invalid Query. 'not-in' filters support a maximum of 10 elements in the value array.]

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use the not-in operator but there are more than 10 results and it can't process it. How can I solve this firebase issue? Is it possible to create a one line solution?

```
const snapshot = await store.collection("users").where("email", "not-in", interacted).get()
```

Comment: If you have more than 10 items, you'll need to run multiple queries and merge the results in your application code. Doing this has been covered quite a few times ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D+query+more+than+10+%5Bjavascript%5D) might be a good starting point), but none of them is a one-liner.

Comment: You may be interested by the following article which explains [how to merge two queries in Cloud Firestore with the JavaScript SDK](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-combined-two-firestore-queries-to-simulate-a-logical-or-query-27d28a43cb2d)